# How to apply Affine3d to Vector3d

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a `Vector3d` containing a list of vertices and I'm trying to apply a rotation on it, but can't find a way to do so:

```
rotationArbitraryAxis(const Vector3d axis, const double angle) {

    Vector3d normAxis = axis.normalized();
    double radians = angle * M_PI / 180.0f;
    AngleAxisd aa(radians, normAxis);
    Affine3d fTransform = Translation3d(normAxis) * aa * Translation3d(-normAxis);

    const double* data = reinterpret_cast<const double*>(m_mesh.points().data());
    Vector3d verts(m_mesh.number_of_vertices());

    std::copy(data, data + m_mesh.number_of_vertices() * 3, verts.data());

    verts *= ???
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are attempting to transform an array of vertices (or normals), the most efficient way is to convert your affine transform to a matrix, and use that to do the transformation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: An `Eigen::Vector3d` can only contain a single 3d-vertex. If you want to store a list of vertices you need a `Eigen::Matrix3Xd`. Your `verts` constructor will fail when compiled without `-DNDEBUG`. How do you want to return the transformed vertices?

Answer (score 0):

As i said in my comment, convert the Affine3d to a matrix, and use that to transform the vertices.

```cpp
    const double* data = reinterpret_cast<const double*>(m_mesh.points().data());

    // I'm assuming you want this as an array of vector3's ???
    std::vector<Vector3d> verts(m_mesh.number_of_vertices());
    std::copy(data, data + m_mesh.number_of_vertices() * 3, verts.data());

    // convert the transform to a matrix
    auto matrix = fTransform.matrix();
    for(auto& vert : verts)
    {
      // now multiply
      vert = matrix * vert;
    }
```

Comment: `Affine3d::matrix()` returns a `4x4` matrix which can't be multiplied with a 3d vector. You can directly multiply an `Affine3d` with a `Vector3d` though.

Comment: As chtz mentioned, the method doesn't work. Also, yes. I decided to use MatrixXd for vertices, but still can't get to multiply it by the Affine3d.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino Did you try `Matrix3Xd`?